# What does `Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression` mean?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am teaching myself Java and am getting this error when I run code in my scrap book in Eclipse:

```
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression
```

Here is my scrap book:

```
Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
int[] nums = {5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4};
sorter.selectionSort(nums);
nums;
```

Here is the Sorter class.

```
public class Sorter {
    public void selectionSort(int[] numbers) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
            int leastPosition = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (numbers[j] < numbers[leastPosition])
                    leastPosition = j;
            }
            int temp = numbers[leastPosition];
            numbers[leastPosition] = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

What is awry? I can't find a missing assignment operator anywhere.

Comment: The bare `nums;` looks weird.  What line does the error refer to?

Comment: I left that as an expression to examine since I want to check if it is sorted after I run my selection sort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem, I think, is the last line of your code:

```
nums;
```

This is an expression, but not a statement; hence the complaint. If you want to examine the contents of `nums`, you can do something like:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print number from array then  use the code

```
for(int (i=0; i<nums.length;i++){
System.out.println(num[i]);
}
```

If you want the proper execution of selection sort then refer [selection sort](http://tutorialdata.com/example/Algorithm/SelectionSortExample.html)